# SQL Server 2005 version 9.00.4035.00 vs 9.00.1399.00

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have two servers with the versions above (9.00.4035.00 vs 9.00.1399.00), but we installed from the same source.

Now some projects don't open. How can I solve this - applying Service Pack 3?

Answer (score 2):

9.00.4035.00 is the build number for SQL Server 2005 SP3, 9.00.1399.00 is the build number for SQL Server 2005 RTM (release to market, ie- the first release).  Applying SP3 to the RTM instance may solve your problem, but it's not guaranteed.  If you can post more information about any errors you're getting we may be able to give you more.

You can make them both 9.00.4035 by installing SP3 to the 9.00.1399.00 server but, like DanBig mentions, SP4 is out so you should consider just installing SP4 on both servers.  It is easy to do, just download the service pack and run its setup.  Of course, make sure you have all the obvious things covered - full server backup, solid backups of all databases, etc.

Dowloads for SP3 and SP4:

- SP3 - [**http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=ae7387c3-348c-4faa-8ae5-949fdfbe59c4**](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=ae7387c3-348c-4faa-8ae5-949fdfbe59c4)
- SP4 - [**http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=b953e84f-9307-405e-bceb-47bd345baece**](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=b953e84f-9307-405e-bceb-47bd345baece)

Also, see [**How to identify your SQL Server version and edition**](http://How%20to%20identify%20your%20SQL%20Server%20version%20and%20edition).

Comment: For instance, apply SP3 didn't work. I couldn't get the errors yet. But I knew some projects doesn't open in the other server. Some of other MS products installed are different on both, maybe the VS use a component installed from other product version.

Comment: @Thomaz By "Projects", do you mean Visual Studio Database projects?  What kind of projects are you referring to?

Comment: Yes, VS 2008 projects. I will indicate to install SP4 in both and see what happens. The problem is stopping working in the two, now work in both , but only opens in that one.

Comment: I'll do this and see what happens. Txs.

Comment: I will make other question: How make the two 9.00.4035.00 or the two 9.00.1399.00 ? Is it easy do this ?

Comment: @Thomaz I've edited my answer with the information

Comment: I noticed MICROSOFT ANALYSIS SERVICES CLIENT TOOLS has the same product number on each. This have any relationship ?

Comment: @Thomaz Analysis Services can get patched / updated independently of the database server.

Comment: "Analysis Services can get patched / updated independently of the database server", yes , but maybe VS is using this and then the version is always different on each server. I need to make it the same , in order to open the same VS project in both. Now it only opens in the same it has been made.

Comment: @Thomaz Install the same service pack on each server for all services and try it.  I can't say it any more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably just install SP4 on both, as it's the latest update available.

Comment: I'll try this and see what happens.